# unflagging a signal does does not exist wipes out the flags

Tags: c#

i have a c# code where removing a flag that does not exist leads to unpredictable results.

scenario #1: removing .LONG_SIDEWAYS wipes out all the flags.

scenario #2: removing a different flag that does not exist still keeps the flags intact

[Fiddle code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/chhXW2)

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    [Flags]
    enum Signals : long
    {
        NONE = 0,
        LONGPULLBACK = 2,
        SHORTPULLBACK = 4,
        RSIOVERSOLD = 8,
        RSIOVERBOUGHT = 16,
        BOUGHTSIGNAL = 32,
        DOUBLEBOUGHTSIGNAL = 64,
        SOLDSIGNAL = 128,
        DOUBLESOLDSIGNAL = 256,
        MATRENDINGLONG = 512,
        MATRENDINGSHORT = 1024,
        LONG_SIDEWAYS = 2014,
        SHORT_SIDEWAYS = 4096,
        MOVEDTOWARDSLONG = 8192,
        MOVEDTOWARDSSHORT = 16384,
        LOOK4LONGBREAKOUT = 32768,
        LOOK4SHORTBREAKOUT = 65536,
        GOTLONGBREAKOUT = 131072,
        GOTSHORTBREAKOUT = 262144
    }

    ;
    public static void Main()
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        Signals signalsobject = Signals.NONE;
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        signalsobject = addSignals(p, signalsobject);
        Console.WriteLine("Scenario #1 removing .LONG_SIDEWAYS that does not exist leads to Signals.NONE");
        Console.WriteLine(signalsobject);
        Console.WriteLine("BEFORE REMOVING" + signalsobject);
        // removing .LONG_SIDEWAYS that does not exist leads to Signals.NONE
        signalsobject = p.UnsetFlag(signalsobject, Signals.LONG_SIDEWAYS);
        Console.WriteLine("AFTER REMOVING SIGNAL THAT DOES NOT EXIST" + signalsobject);
        // readd and test 
        Console.WriteLine("Scenario #2 removing ..MATRENDINGLONGS that does not exist leads to showing the flags kept as is.");
        signalsobject = addSignals(p, signalsobject);
        Console.WriteLine("BEFORE REMOVING" + signalsobject);
        // removing ..MATRENDINGLONGS that does not exist leads to showing the flags kept as is.
        signalsobject = p.UnsetFlag(signalsobject, Signals.MATRENDINGLONG);
        Console.WriteLine("AFTER REMOVING SIGNAL THAT DOES NOT EXIST" + signalsobject);
    }

    private static Signals addSignals(Program p, Signals signalsobject)
    {
        signalsobject = p.SetFlag(signalsobject, Program.Signals.LONGPULLBACK);
        signalsobject = p.SetFlag(signalsobject, Program.Signals.SHORTPULLBACK);
        signalsobject = p.SetFlag(signalsobject, Program.Signals.RSIOVERSOLD);
        signalsobject = p.SetFlag(signalsobject, Program.Signals.RSIOVERBOUGHT);
        signalsobject = p.SetFlag(signalsobject, Program.Signals.DOUBLEBOUGHTSIGNAL);
        signalsobject = p.SetFlag(signalsobject, Program.Signals.SOLDSIGNAL);
        signalsobject = p.SetFlag(signalsobject, Program.Signals.DOUBLESOLDSIGNAL);
        return signalsobject;
    }

    Signals SetFlag(Signals orignal, Signals newFlag)
    {
        return orignal | newFlag;
    }

    Signals UnsetFlag(Signals original, Signals flag2remove)
    {
        return original & (~flag2remove);
    }

    // Works with "None" as well
    Signals ToogleFlag(Signals orignal, Signals flag2toggle)
    {
        return orignal ^ flag2toggle;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your first problem:

```cpp
LONG_SIDEWAYS = 2014,
```

These look like they're meant to be single-bit masks so the correct value would be `211`, or `2048`. The value `2014` that you're currently using would wipe out:

```
1024  MATRENDINGSHORT
 512  MATRENDINGLONG
 256  DOUBLESOLDSIGNAL
 128  SOLDSIGNAL
  64  DOUBLEBOUGHTSIGNAL
  16  RSIOVERBOUGHT
   8  RSIOVERSOLD
   4  SHORTPULLBACK
   2  LONGPULLBACK
====
2014
```

These cover *all* the bits you added when calling `addSignals()` so will end up giving you an empty mask.

---

For your second issue, as per your code comment:

> ... removing `MATRENDINGLONGS` that does not exist leads to showing the flags kept as is.

Assuming I understand your comment, this is to be expected. You are clearing a bit that is *already* clear so no change will be evident.

It's the same as if you have a fruit basket containing only oranges and bananas, and decide to take out all the apples. Then you're somehow concerned about the fact it has no apples :-)

If you try setting or toggling it (adding an apple), you should see a change.